# Как карты определяют место с точностью до дома?

Tags: wifi, карты, геолокация

Собственно сабж,

очень интересно как это возможно, что для этого используется, какие данные ?
Какие есть варианты ?
**UPD**
Имел ввиду с точек по Wi-fi

*Сделали опыт:*
Через телефон сделали точку, раздали мобильный интернет, и все же определил где мы.

Comment: Триангуляция же.

Comment: @Сахарок, триангуляция сигнала точки доступа на три спутника Google ?

Comment: Мне вот тоже интересно, как новые карты в OS X Maverics нашли положение моего ноутбука подключенного к инету через обычного домашнего провайдера...

Comment: @pustserg Вот после OS X Maverics этот вопрос и появился)
@Сахарок что за триангуляция? можно чуть подробнее

Answer (score 4, accepted):

По улицам иногда ездит шпиенский автомобиль от компании Google. На автомашине установлено сканирующее устройство, которое засекает работающие wi-fi устройства и делает их привязку MAC адрес -> гео-координаты. Такой метод называется [Wifi Positioning System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_positioning_system)

Далее дело уже техники: запрос на сервера гугль по засеченным mac адресам, триангуляция, ваши координаты. Таким способом можно координаты и без наличия GPS приемника. Конечно такой способ иногда дает сбои. Допустим если wi-fi передатчик передвинули то и координаты будут неверны.

**Update**

[Так устроен алгоритм триангуляции](http://habrahabr.ru/post/161195/) (немного математики)

Comment: Дошли и до этого варианта, но в Алмате мало вероятно это, как и в Российских глубинках )

Comment: В Алмате работает Skyhook Wireless один из провайдеров WPS так что все правильно.

Answer (score 2):

Существует несколько способов определения местонахождения мобильного телефона, а заодно и его владельца. Самыми распространёнными являются два: по встроенному датчику GPS и по сотовым вышкам оператора. Так как далеко не во всех мобильных телефонах встроены GPS модули, более популярным способом пока что остаётся именно поиск местонахождения мобильного телефона по сотовым вышкам оператора, также известный как Cell ID.

Comment: Это про мобильные телефоны, да их через вышки, высчитываю, находят, в нашем случае же ноутбук который подключенный к вай-фаю )

Comment: ноутбук по вайфаю также может делать триангуляцию. Вопрос только в том, где взять координаты вайфая. А это делает очень просто андроид устройствами - они смотрят доступные вайфай точки, а свои координаты они обычно знают. То есть, решают обратную задачу.

Comment: Откуда вайфай точки знают свои координаты?

Comment: @Barmaley♦ видимо вычисляются через зону раздачи, и как то еще ?